# What are potential pitfalls when casting from bigger to smaller numeric types?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

Assume I am using a function `foo` that returns a `double` but I'm working with `float`s in my program (as is customary for example in many computer graphics applications). 
I can't be bothered to rewrite `foo` for `float` because I don't use in in many places and the space (and potentially also speed) overhead are not significant enough to justify the time for this. Making `foo` a function template that works with multiple types isn't an option either because the function is from a library.

I have multiple options to deal with this situation:

1) Use the function as is:

```
float f = foo();
```

This gives a compiler warning "possible loss of data" that I would like to eliminate because I'm sure that the loss of precision is no issue in this particular case.

2) Explicitely cast to float:

```
float f = static_cast<float>(foo());
```

Eliminates the warning and makes clear for a reader that I am converting to float here, but makes it harder to quickly grasp what is going on, especially when the line becomes longer or if I have to cast multiple parameters.

3) Write a wrapper that hides the conversion to float

```
float foo_float() { return static_cast<float>foo(); }
float f = foo_float();
```

No warning and is easier to read than (2) but potentially leads to many functions/lambdas that don't really add new functionality.

**I would like to know:**

1. Are there more ways to deal with this situation?
2. Am I missing pitfalls in one of the three approaches?

Note that the same problem can occure for integer types when I can be sure that the result of a function fits into a smaller type that I use.

Comment: I guess you know already, but as you are asking...you are completely ignoring potential overflow. Btw I dont get your argument of `static_cast` making it harder to grasp what is going on. Without the cast the reader has no chance at all to grasp what is going on...

Comment: Btw. translating "graphics" to "OpenGL": It uses `float` in many places to save storage and lower bus traffic to GPU. However, due to loss of precision (and potential overflows), this has to be handled carefully. Thus, it could improve results if conversion to float is done as late as possible. In the past, an often discussed topic was visualization of solar system (a usual example for scene graphs). With realistic numbers, the precision of float was usually unacceptable for calculating with world coordinates, but not an issue in eye space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> ```
> Are there more ways to deal with this situation?
> ```

Yes, for instance dealing with the overflow - [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) has library called [Numeric Conversion](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/html/index.html) that exposes and helps deal with the situation. (*in particular* `numeric_cast`)

> ```
> Am I missing pitfalls in one of the three approaches?
> ```

Overflow. Also, leaving a known warning of this kind in code is often not acceptable.

---

> ### Overview
>
> The Boost Numeric Conversion library is a collection of tools to
>   describe and perform conversions between values of different numeric
>   types.
>
> The library includes a special alternative for a subset of
>   std::numeric_limits<>, the bounds<> traits class, which provides a
>   consistent way to obtain the boundary values for the range of a
>   numeric type.
>
> It also includes a set of trait classes which describes the
>   compile-time properties of a conversion from a source to a target
>   numeric type. Both arithmetic and user-defined numeric types can be
>   used.
>
> A policy-based converter object which uses conversion_traits to select
>   an optimized implementation is supplied. Such implementation uses an
>   optimal range checking code suitable for the source/target
>   combination.
>
> ```
> The converter's out-of-range behavior can be customized via an OverflowHandler policy.
> For floating-point to integral conversions, the rounding mode can be selected via the Float2IntRounder policy.
> A custom low-level conversion routine (for UDTs for instance) can be passed via a RawConverter policy.
> The optimized automatic range-checking logic can be overridden via a UserRangeChecker policy.
> ```

Comment: Especially `numeric_cast` as a range checking alternative to `static_cast` is new to me, thanks for the hint. I will leaf the question open for a bit to see if there is more input and accept an answer later.

Comment: @AlbertM i was thinking of that in particular, but couldn't quickly find the reference